# Could not initialize Xv output

Tags: linux, gstreamer, x11, xorg

I have installed gstreamer-1.0 on my target board.
When I run the below command:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/home/test.mp4" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
>
> I am getting the following output:
>
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>
> ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
>
> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0: Could not initialise Xv output
>
> Additional debug info:
>
> xvimagesink.c(1765): gst_xvimagesink_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
>
> Could not open display (null)
>
> Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>
> Freeing pipeline ..

Please suggest some solution to make the pipeline work.

Regards,

Sainath

Answer (score 0):

Hm do you have libxv somewhere? 
Find 
what happens when you check `gst-inspect-1.0 xvimagesink` ? 
Also there is library path mentioned (`| grep Filename`).. you can ldd it:

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstxvimagesink.so
```

I had some problems with this as well.. try to install libxv-dev or libxv1.. maybe dev is safer.